# 6 While creating a react app from scratch (without using create-react-app) using parcel bundler, the parcel throws the following error:

Tags: reactjs

Build failed.

Error: Expected content key 8e22976280a5d25d to exist

Error: Expected content key 8e22976280a5d25d to exist
at nullthrows (C:\Users\sonuh\OneDrive\Desktop\PetPuja\node_modules\nullthrows\nullthrows.js:7:15)
at AssetGraph.getNodeIdByContentKey (C:\Users\sonuh\OneDrive\Desktop\PetPuja\node_modules@parcel\graph\lib\ContentGraph.js:67:38)
at C:\Users\sonuh\OneDrive\Desktop\PetPuja\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\SymbolPropagation.js:52:82
at Array.map ()
at propagateSymbols (C:\Users\sonuh\OneDrive\Desktop\PetPuja\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\SymbolPropagation.js:52:61)
at AssetGraphBuilder.build (C:\Users\sonuh\OneDrive\Desktop\PetPuja\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\requests\AssetGraphRequest.js:174:62)
at async Object.run (C:\Users\sonuh\OneDrive\Desktop\PetPuja\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\requests\AssetGraphRequest.js:62:37)
at async RequestTracker.runRequest (C:\Users\sonuh\OneDrive\Desktop\PetPuja\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:673:20)
at async Object.run (C:\Users\sonuh\OneDrive\Desktop\PetPuja\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\requests\BundleGraphRequest.js:106:11)
at async RequestTracker.runRequest (C:\Users\sonuh\OneDrive\Desktop\PetPuja\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:673:20)

How can I solve this?

Comment: `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force .parcel-cache`
when you run Remove-Item -Recurse -Force .parcel-cache, it will forcefully and recursively delete the .parcel-cache directory and all its contents. Use this command carefully, as it permanently removes the specified directory and its content. **then run** `npx parcel <entry point(like index.html)>`

Comment: If this is meant to be the answer to this problem you should post as an answer, not a comment.